# transaction rollback sqlalchemy - is it safe to do?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a `db.session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.id == some_id).delete()`
like operation in my Flask code. And it fails when some other table refers to `SomeModel` with a foreign key. It gives the following error:

`(psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) update or delete on table "some_model" violates foreign key constraint "some_model_id_fkey" on table "other_model" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "other_model".`

Also any later operation will suffer from this error:
`psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

I found the solution for this

```
    try:
        db.session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.id == some_id).delete()
        db.session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        db.session.rollback()
```

However my question is, can the `rollback()` here have side-effects? Like some other operation being carried out somewhere in the Flask app could also be rolled back if this is called before the commit() ? I am not sure about this because after this error any other operation on `db.session` seems to be failing as I have written the error starting with `current transaction...`

Comment: That depends on when you started the transaction. Everything you did after that will be undone. But once you hit an error, you have no choice but to rollback anyway.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is there way to check if the delete is safe to call? I mean I can check if there are any foreign key for the `other_model` but what if there is another model like this.

Comment: You have to know what you did in.this transaction. After all, you wrote the code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe True. To understand better, can we say that the transaction starts from where the last `db.session.commit()` was called in the app which might be any place? Then it is kind of indefinite to know exactly what kind of transaction is being rollbacked right?

Comment: If you don't know and deliberately set the transaction boundaries in your application, you have a problem that is much bigger than the one you are concerned about.

Comment: I think I now know, the transaction starts and ends with `db.session.commit()` therefore it is not going to be problem